# Urn Problem: Conditional Probability

Tags: probability

**Problem.** An urn contains 4 black balls and 6 white balls. 3 balls are drawn from the urn without replacement. What is the probability that 1 black ball and 2 white balls are drawn, given that at least 2 of the balls in the sample are white?

**Solution Attempt.** Let $A$ be the event that 1 black ball and 2 white balls are drawn and $B$ be the event that at least 2 of the balls in the sample are white. Event $B$ has two cases: either the third ball is black or white. Thus
$$P(A)= \frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}} \hspace{1 cm} P(B) = \frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}+\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}=2\frac{\binom{6}{2}\binom{4}{0}\binom{4}{1}}{\binom{10}{3}}$$
By Bayes' Theorem,
$$P(A|B)=\frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}$$
At this point, I'm stuck. I don't know what $P(B|A)$ is. I tried the other form (where the numerator is $P(A \cap B)$) but I don't what that is either. Any ideas and/or tips? Thanks!

Comment: You might do better with $C$ the event that all three are white so $A \cap C=\emptyset$ and $A\cup C=B$, so the two cases of $B$ are $A$ and $C$.  The question is asking for $P(A \mid B)=\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(B)}$

Comment: PS: $\mathsf P(B\mid A)=1$, because it is the probability that *at least 2* balls are white when given that *exactly* 2 of them are.  In the same vein $A\cap B=A$ because $A\subset B$.  Thus $$\mathsf P(A\mid B) = \dfrac{\mathsf P(A)}{\mathsf P(B)}$$

Comment: @GrahamKemp I was also thinking that $P(B|A)=1$ so that $P(A|B)= P(A)/P(B)$ , but this is my first to encounter such deduction so I dismissed my thought as false, though it made complete sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  $B$ is the event that either 2 from 6 white and 1 from 4 black, or 3 from 6 white and 0 from 4 black are drawn.  There is no special 'third' ball counted separately from the other two.

$$\mathsf P(B)=\dfrac{\dbinom 62\dbinom41+\dbinom63\dbinom 40}{\dbinom{10}3}$$

---

If you *do* count the third ball separately you must (1) also do so in both numerator *and* denominator, and (2) include the favoured case where the first two are of different colours and the third is white.

$$\mathsf P(B)=\dfrac{\dbinom 62\!\dbinom 40~\dbinom41\!\dbinom40+\dbinom62\!\dbinom 40~\dbinom 40\!\dbinom 41+\dbinom 61\!\dbinom 41~\dbinom 51\!\dbinom 30}{\dbinom{10}2~\dbinom 81}$$

Which evaluates to the same result but is far less elegant.

Comment: I got the $P(B)$ now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

A simple way is to consider the sample space available

after conditioning is {2W,1B} + {3W}

Thus $Pr = \dfrac{\binom62\binom41}{\binom62\binom41+\binom63}=\frac34$

**PS**

The question is in effect asking for
P(exactly two white)/P(at least two white)
= n(exactly two white)/n(at least two white)